# Drop one Primary key and add another in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key, ddl, alter-table

I have a table that I need to drop the primary key which is a compound key and make it a primary key based on a single value.
I dropped the original Primary key:

```
SQL> alter table depositor
  2  drop primary key;

  Table altered.
```

But when I try try add the new back I get an error message.

```
SQL> alter table depositor
   2  add primary key (account_number);

      alter table depositor
                *
      ERROR at line 1:
   ORA-02437: cannot validate (ZSMITH.SYS_C0084996) - primary key violated
```

Was the PK not dropped?   Did I not add it back correctly?

Comment: Are you sure that the new primary key column is all distinct and never null on your existing data?

Comment: That was it duplicate account numbers

Answer (score 3):

On an existing table, you can only create a primary key if the data in that table would really work as a primary key (i.e. all values distinct and not null).